# sql select with tags using like or regexp

Tags: sql, regex, filter, tags

I'm having an issue where I really don't know how to fix it. So I have a many to many relationship model with the following tables: 'posts', 'tags', 'posts_to_tags'.
Say I want to get all the posts having tags starting by 's' and 't'. I use the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.id  
FROM posts o  
JOIN posts_to_tags ot  ON o.id = ot.post_id  
JOIN tags t  ON ot.tag_id = t.id  
WHERE t.name REGEXP '^s|^t'  
GROUP BY o.id
HAVING COUNT(o.id) = 2
```

This works fine in most cases but not always. For example if there is a post having the following tags: smee, smooth, lala
the query will succeed even though there is no tag starting by 't' (there are 2 tags starting by 's'). Here the post should also have a tag starting by 't'.
Does anyone have any tip on how to fix that?
I hope I made the problem clear to understand.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mean the tags should contain *at least one* match starting with *each* character, right? So `smee, tooth, lala` would match for your example.

Comment: yes, exactly that! Of course the 's' and 't' is something to test on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want all posts that have a tag that starts with 's' and another that starts with 't'.  You need to change the `having` clause:

```
SELECT o.id  
FROM posts o  
JOIN posts_to_tags ot  ON o.id = ot.post_id  
JOIN tags t  ON ot.tag_id = t.id  
WHERE t.name REGEXP '^s|^t'  
GROUP BY o.id
HAVING count(distinct left(t.name, 1)) = 2;
```

Also, you don't need `select distinct` when you are using `group by`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon! It almost works. The 's' and 't' is simply an example of course. I tried with 's' and 's' but then it doesn't work. Any ideas? And thank you about the groub by / distinct.

Comment: @IoannisPanteleakis . . . `'s'` and `'s'` won't work because they are the same.  You should provide a real example that you are working with.

Comment: @GorgonLinoff You're right, after thinking about it a bit more, I just realized that it doesn't even make much sense (the double 's'). It's a simple personal project to actually learn cakephp and trying to figure out how things work. So it looks like your solution works. Would you please explain to how the distinct left() is working here? If the REGEXP would contain terms with more characters, would I need to change the left(t.name, ...) part? Thank you again, really appreciated.

Comment: @IoannisPanteleakis . . . The `distinct left` is just counting the number of distinct letters that match the query.  Because everything starts with "s" or "t", there are only two choices.  So, it makes sure both are present.

Comment: Thank you a lot. It's much more clear now. Only thing I don't complete get, is the second parameter of left(). If I REGEXP 'sm' instead of 's', would I need to change it to left( t.name, 2 )?
BTW, I'm new to stackoverflow, so it looks like I still can't vote up your answer, but I will as soon as I can. Thank you

Comment: Yes, if you were looking for a two letter prefix, you would change the `1` to `2`.